# css file is not working in Spring Theme module. properties files are loaded properly but css are not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I configured my confugration file ie. dispatcher-servlet.xml file for Themes using following  beans

```
<bean id="themeSource" class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
    <property name="basenamePrefix" value="theme-" />
</bean>

<!-- Theme Change Interceptor and Resolver definition -->
<bean id="themeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="theme" />
</bean>
<bean id="themeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">
    <property name="defaultThemeName" value="default" />
</bean>
```

I have added 3 properties
as theme-black.properties,theme-blue.properties,theme-default.properties under the source directory.

in each properties file I added key-value pair as following

```
style=style/blue.css
style=style/black.css
style=style/default.css
```

i put style folder under Web-Content .
problem is this ResourceBundleThemeSource loaded properties file successfully but could not able to load css file.

In JSP file I have added follwing code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:theme code='style'/>"
type="text/css" />
```

for changing

```
<span style="float: right;"> <a href="?theme=default">
        default</a> &nbsp;| <a href="?theme=blue">blue</a> &nbsp;| <a
    href="?theme=black">black</a>
</span>
```

Please help me out if any issue is there........ please please please > Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Spring's theme support, however I spot a little mistake in your URL.

First your URLs are relative. You should always have absolute URLs (starting with `/`).

Second, when using any URL, you should use `<c:url>` or `<spring:url>` so that correct context prefix is used:

```
<spring:url var="cssUrl">
    <jsp:attribute name="value"><spring:theme code="style"/></jsp:attribute>
</spring:url>
```

Comment: Hi Pavel , Thanks for your quick reply , but I didn't get you. I believe I haven't use any url in my code. If you know can you please guide me. Thanks....

Comment: `href="<spring:theme code="style"/>"` - here you are using URL for your CSS file. You should at least add leading slash `/` in your properties. Processing it through URL tag is optional and depends on your use-case. If the CSS file is always part of the final WAR, you should process it. If it is an external reference or reference to another context, it is a bit more complex situation.

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as specifying the location of your static content (in you `application-config.xml`), and the path from which to access them:

`<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>`

And next you edit the themes properties file with :
`style=resources/style/blue.css`

And put `blue.css` file into: `webapp/resources/themes`

Now you can load `css` file using:

1. `"resources/themes/blue.css"` in `href`
2. Or using `style` in `code` of `spring:theme` tag.

This works for me.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know whether you have put the bean `themeChangeInterceptor` ref under bean `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` . If you have done that , then please remove that from there and put that inside the `<mvc:interceptors>`tag like below

```
<mvc:interceptors>
<ref bean="themeChangeInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```